# How do bulk actions affect a ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

I'm confused about how Concurrent Dictionaries lock their resources.

For example, if I run a method that iterates over every item in the Dictionary and edits its value in a thread and I try to read the value of a key from another thread:

Will the second thread be accessing a snapshot of the Dictionary?
If not, will it access the updated entry if that one has already been updated?

Comment: If you ever need a snapshot of a `ConcurrentDictionary` for whatever reason, use the [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.toarray) method. The internal structures of the class will be locked while the snapshot is taken, so don't do it very frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrent Dictionaries are thread-safe that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner whereas write is protected with lock. For implementation details, please check [ConcurrentDictionary](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs).

Answer (score 0):

The second thread will be accessing the updated dictionary.  All a `ConcurrentDictionary` does is provide put a lock on the collection on any add or remove operations.  Read operations are unaffected.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/?view=netframework-4.8#thread-synchronization-in-the-net-framework-10-and-20-collections)